# Firefox 3.6 - Navigation Toolbar - Google search box language

Tags: windows-7, firefox, google-search

Using Win7 Home Premium with Firefox 3.6

I like using the Google search box in the Navigation Toolbar because it's quicker to do a search but as I am English and I am in Thailand it seems to do the search within www.google.co.th by default and so nearly everything on the google search page that comes up is in the Thai language (which is lots of weird squiggles).

Is there any way to default the search to google.co.uk or google.com ?? and hence be in English.

I can't see anything obvious to change the default search or language??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Add to search bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3682) extension will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this i have found this link...

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15127/make-firefox-show-google-results-for-default-address-bar-searches/

which makes it even easier to do a google search in the address bar.  It essentially removes the default 'I feel lucky' search within the firefox address bar and thus brings up the results in a normal google search page.