# Change the default Google search domain

Tags: firefox, google-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox 3.6 - Navigation Toolbar - Google search box language problem](https://superuser.com/questions/111160/firefox-3-6-navigation-toolbar-google-search-box-language-problem)

I am currently working from Germany. From Firefox, if I give something to search in the Google search box in the browser, it is automatically taking me to `google.de`, and is returning results which is of no use for me.

Is there any chance, that I can change the default to `google.com` or `google.co.in` or `google.co.uk`, something like that which gives me English results?

Comment: Duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/111160/firefox-3-6-navigation-toolbar-google-search-box-language-problem

Comment: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/08/change-googles-search-domain-in-google.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for any keyword using Firefox' builtin search box. It takes you to `google.de`. Now go to Google's homepage, and click on click *Google.com in English* in the footer. Next time you use the browser's search box, it will take you to `google.com`.

Comment: +1. It works. But how does it work? Using a cookie? It seems to be a setting per browser, not per computer.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: yes, it's cookie based. If you install a new Firefox search plugin, it will only effect a specific browser (a Firefox profile, to be precise).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firefox search box (on the right side of the address navigation bar), you can download other search engine plugins from [here](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/google-search-plugins.html). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You will find [**here**](http://bmdixon.wordpress.com/2007/11/06/change-default-google-search-in-firefox/) instructions on how to change the default Google search used by Firefox.

> It’s a very simple fix, basically all
>   you need to do is navigate to the
>   firefox directory (“c:\program
>   files\mozilla firefox” is the default
>   for windows) then open the
>   “searchplugins” folder.
>
> Next you need to edit the “google.xml”
>   file and change this line:
>
> ```
> <Url type=”text/html” method=”GET” template=”http://www.google.de/search”>
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> <Url type=”text/html” method=”GET” template=”http://www.google.com/search”>
> ```
>
> or whichever google locality you wish to use. I also changed this line (but
>   i’m not sure if it’s necessary):
>
> ```
> <SearchForm>http://www.google.com/firefox</SearchForm>
> ```
>
> Then re-open firefox and search away!

Comment: +1 to counter the unjustified down vote. What is wrong with this answer?