# How do I change the region of my google search in firefox?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the default Google search domain](https://superuser.com/questions/111910/change-the-default-google-search-domain)

I'm in Australia, but use a macbook from the uk.

When I use the google search in firefox, it goes to google.com instead of google.com.au.

How can I change this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/111910/change-the-default-google-search-domain/111913#111913

Comment: The other article is for windows pcs, its doesn't say how to fix the problem on a mac, it isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://www.google.com/ncr. This will install a "no country redirect" cookie that avoids country specific search results (and no longer will forward from *google.com.au* to *google.com*. Now If you ever want to reset your browser to enable this feature, just delete your google cookies.

Comment: this is the opposite of what i am trying to do.